# What's wrong with this answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

One of my answer is receiving downvote and I don't understand the reason.

It seems users are following the first downvote blindly. But having @fschmengler comment makes me wonder why?

[Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Blog_Helper_Data' not found in /home/teamgack/public_html/lafzz.com/app/Mage.php on line 547](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116388/fatal-error-class-mage-blog-helper-data-not-found-in-home-teamgack-public-ht/116390#116390#answer-116390)

Answer (score 5):

Your case is a rare one.
Usually people don't state reasons for why they downvote something.
You got an explanation and a valid one I might say.
Generally speaking, people are encouraged to state a reason for downvoting, but you cannot enforce that. If people want to downvote they can.
There are rules against serial downvoting (or upvoting).  If there are a lot of targeted votes in a short peropd of time, they are reverted the next day. If there are targeted votes in a long period of time they appear in some moderator report.
I checked the report for you and there is nothing wrong with it, so you are save.
People downvoted the content, not the person in your specific case.

Comment: Thanks for reply Marius. In my understanding the answer is serving the question. I don't find the exact reason for down vote. Is it wrong answer? Obviously I could edit and improve it, but I want to see the right answer to this question and can be compared to it (happy to get more down vote if answer deserves).

Comment: The first comment on your answer states that your solution hides the problem, it does not solve it.  This is a valid reason.